# SmarterAsp.Net Connection String

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a program I wrote in ASP.Net MVC.  When I run the file inside Visual Studio it runs great.  I uploaded the file on SmarterAsp.Net.  Now everything comes up except my database part of the file and I get an error 52 when I bring up the database part.  Here is the link to my site.  http://dwmurphy67-001-site2.smarterasp.net/.  When you click on the tab that says patches that's where my database should come up.  This is what SmarterAsp.Net gave me for the connection strings:

ASP.net

"Data Source=SQL5011.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9B2856_Product;User Id=DB_9B2856_Product_admin;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;"

Classic ASP

"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SQL5011.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9B2856_Product;User Id=DB_9B2856_Product_admin;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;"

This is what I have in my web.config file:

```
 <add name= "Product" connectionString="Data Source=SQL5011.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9B2856_Product;User Id=DB_9B2856_Product_admin;Password:#######"/>
<add name="ProductEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Product.csdl|res://*/Models.Product.ssdl|res://*/Models.Product.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Product.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="EmailmeContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=EmailmeContext-20140604141117; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|EmailmeContext-20140604141117.mdf"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Can anyone help me with this?

I know somewhere my connection string is wrong where I'm hooking up to the database on SmarterAsp.Net.

Comment: `(localdb)\v11.0;` this won't work in a production environment.  Change these to the real SQL server connection.

Comment: And also, if that's the real password for your SQL connection, you might want to remove it from this post!

Comment: Thanks for your help that seems to have done the trick for that problem.  Now it's just giving me a login error.  This is what I'm getting now:  SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'IFC\WIN5062$'.  This is what I have in my web.config code:

Comment: i left a greeting in your database...